# how do I display cakephp query result in editable form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

how do I display cakephp query result in editable form such that it is displayed in an input form for edit.
The code below displays query result in a table

```
<?php foreach ($examination as $key => $exam): ?>
<td><?php echo !empty($exam['ExamCalendar']['reg_exam_date']) ? date('d-m-Y', strtotime($exam['ExamCalendar']['reg_exam_date'])) : '--'; ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you currently getting an output of text with your current code, you just want it in an editable field? or are you not getting an output at all? or you getting errors? Also at quick glance it seems you might want to echo the `<td>`  and `</td>` as well and keep it all in the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the issue using the below code

```
<table>
<tr>                                    
<?php foreach ($examination as $key => $exam): ?>
<td>
<?php echo !empty($exam['ExamCalendar']['reg_exam_date']) ? $this->Form->input('Result Verification Status',['value'=>date('d-m-Y', strtotime($exam['ExamCalendar']['reg_exam_date']))]) : '--'; ?>
</td>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

This displays and input box with value from the query